# Input type="date" giving previous date as reult in AngularJS ng-model. Why?

Tags: angularjs, html

When I select any date using datepicker, it gives previous day date. I want to know why it is so. Also how to solve it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <div>
        <form novalidate class="simple-form">
            Date: <input type="date" ng-model="user.date" /><br />
        </form>
        <pre>user = {{user}}</pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo for the same.
[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/p8qoTsLdfXNCtp3bLJAF?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess... You live to the east of Great Britain.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.

When you insert the date as `2016-04-02`, it is being converted to a `Date` object at midnight according to your local settings.

> The JavaScript Date object provides uniform behavior across platforms. The time value can be passed between systems to represent the same moment in time and if used to create a local date object, will reflect the local equivalent of the time.

In order to provide this uniform behavior, it is converted to the UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) date with the information regarding your timezone attached to your date.

I live in Moldova (Europe) and when I insert `2015-05-15` in your plunker  I get `user = {"date":"2015-05-14T21:00:00.000Z"}`. This is because Moldova is in `GMT+3` timezone and when it's midnight here, it is still `9PM, 24th of May` according to UTC (or GMT).

If, however, you will give the possibility to insert a datetime string and you'll provide a noon time, you'll get the same day. Insert `2015-05-15T12:00:00` in this [plunker fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/FTHl0zuvdraNRbt026Pk?p=preview) and check it yourself.

If you want to create a date that won't have the `Date.UTC` method:

```
var d = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
```

Comment: Nice explanation.. +1 .. Isn't there any default date setting, so is there anyway we can have such `Date.UTC` format declare only one in a global way? or something like it..

Comment: So how did it start working..after setting date manually in below answer(it is not showing date lag in date)? Just curious to know. Thanks ;)

Comment: @PankajParkar I'm not sure I understood your question.. can you please describe it more?

Comment: do look at the comments section of below answer

Comment: @PankajParkar oh, I see now. When you first instantiate a date, you create a date object (that contains current time) that is bound to the date input. Now, because you've initialized it using `new Date()`, it contains hours and minutes, BUT it is also affected by your timezone (check in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/maeCsX0KlW3uKtvDlSQV?p=preview) if the hour displayed equals with your actual hour. it shouldn't).

Comment: @PankajParkar When you change the date using the datepicker, you actually change the Year, Month, Day of the same date, you don't create a new one or make a copy of it. And because the number of hours remains, when adjusted for your timezone it still gives you correct date. HOWEVER, this solution won't work if you'll try to use the datepicker at 1AM - after adjusting the timezone, it will show you the previous date.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of mistakes:

- `ng-app` is not defined
- `ng-controller` is not defined
- you don't have `app.js` with module name and controller

Try to initialize the date first:

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', []);

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

    MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function MainCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.user = new Date();

    }
}());
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form class="simple-form">
      Date: <input type="date" ng-model="user" />
    </form>
    <pre>user = {{ user }}</pre>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/maeCsX0KlW3uKtvDlSQV)

Comment: whoops, forgot to save plunkr. Done

Comment: cool.. that is it.. +1,  could you please add explanation why it was not working? & how it go worked just by initializing `new Date()` object?

Comment: Initialising the date with `new Date()` object, initialise the date to current date and it shows the correct key value pair in object, but I cannot initialise it with the current date as it display the date selected. Which will create problem. I also have same question why it is working correctly on initialisation with the current date.

Comment: @Kartik check the comments on my answer, I've explained it there. Initializing the date first will work incorrectly if you'll try to use it at 1AM for instance - it will show you the previous day

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @iulian answer, I came to know the modifications required according to my zone.
If you want to know the the date selected according to your timezone then checkout your timezone @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country and then set that much difference in obtained date string.

For eg. I am in India and my UTC timezone is UTC+5:30, So to get exact date and time I need to add 5hrs and 30 minutes in the obtained result with sign.

`added 5.5(hrs)*60(minutes)*60(sec)*1000(miliseconds) as follows`

`$scope.user.date = new Date(+new Date($scope.user.date) + 5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

Here is the demo for the same. [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RhI8GMqKOePSGdbxB1sk?p=preview)

Change value according to your timezone and get the exact values.

Thanks